# How to find the physical path of a GSP file in a deployed grails application

Tags: grails

I need to find out the physical path of a grails GSP file.

My requirement is that I want to create a new layout file at run-time and use that in the application.

I have been able to achieve this without problem when the application runs on jetty (grails run-app), however, when I deploy the app on Jboss, the path at which the file needs to be created changes.

So, ideally I would like to find out at runtime using some magical utility the path of a particular GSP (lets say main.gsp layout file) and I need to create my new layout in the same directory in which main.gsp reside.

Any pointers?

-Deepak

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I suspect that this isn't really a meaningful question in the context of a WARred up web app -- after all, you don't actually have a folder to write into.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some groovy code to lookup the layout-folder path in the production environment (eg. when deployed as war on jboss):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

...

File layoutFolder = ApplicationHolder.application.parentContext.getResource("WEB-INF/grails-app/views/layouts").file      
def absolutePath = layoutFolder.absolutePath
println "Absolute Path to Layout Folder: ${absolutePath}"
File newLayoutFile = new File(layoutFolder, "foo.gsp")
```

To use the newly created layout, you probably will need to restart the web-application or the container, since the views are chached in production mode.

Comment: What does that code give you if you do a "grails prod run-war"?

Comment: Did you ask that question out of curiosity? Or do you know that it does not work ;) I have to admit that I did not try this one. It used to work with deployed and exploded wars for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's a definitive way...

```
grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("WEB-INF/grails-app/views/path/to/my.gsp").file.toString()
```

Out of controllers (ex. bootstrap)? Just inject..

```
def grailsApplication
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

In controllers you can use

```
grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("/relative/path/").getFile().toString()
```