# How to find a list of all views/templates in folder a grails app

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a folder in my application - and if I know the template name, I can load the template easily with the standard `<g:render template="../templateDir/templateName" />`.  This setup is so that I can use an admin UI to define whats included in pages.

I'm trying to figure out a way to determine what are the available templates so I can display them in the admin interface.
Looking at : [How to find the physical path of a GSP file in a deployed grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491067/how-to-find-the-physical-path-of-a-gsp-file-in-a-deployed-grails-application)

I've tried the methods in there  - and while they may work in production when I'm deploying via war - I'm interested in a method that works in development (running inside my IDE) and when deployed via war.

Comment: It's just the path that's not the same. You can use [Environment](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/api/grails/util/Environment.html) to check which one you need.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd prefer a simple solution that doesn't require me doing that check - but if that's the only option, oh well.

Comment: Maybe GrailsResourceLocator can help you on that.